# Permission Denied (publickey) Error when Cloning GitHub Repository as Collaborator

Tags: windows, flutter, git, github, ssh

I recently joined a project on GitHub as a collaborator. The project's repository has been shared with me, and I have added my public key to my GitHub account. However, when I clone the project from GitHub and run the command 'flutter pub get' to resolve dependencies, I encounter the following error message:

```
Resolving dependencies... (8.0s)
Git error. Command: `git fetch`
stdout: 
stderr: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
exit code: 128
```

I'm looking for assistance in understanding why I'm facing this problem despite being added as a collaborator to the project on GitHub. Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening you probably forgot to do some step on the tutorial about adding SSH keys to your account.

Follow carefully all the instructions on this guide and try again:
https://docs.github.com/pt/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account